# Remove an element on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a menu which pops up during my program but I don't know the best way to close the menu when the close button is clicked. Here is the menu:

```
that.dom.container.style.height = $(that.dom.container).height()+"px";
                    that.dom.container.innerHTML =
                        '<div class="E_Trigger_WrapperInner">'+
                            '<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' + i18n('triggerjs.running.head') + '</h2>'+
                            '<div class="E_Trigger_Warning">' + i18n('triggerjs.running.info') + '</div>'+
                            '<div class="E_Form_ButtonSet">'+
                                '<button class="E_Form_Button">' + i18n('triggerjs.running.close') + '</button>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
```

I have tried the below solution but this leaves a small bit of the box remaining like shown in the image.

```
 $('div.E_Form_ButtonSet button', that.dom.container).click( function (e) { 
                        that.dom.container.style.display = "none";
                    } );
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can test : (with your own code) 
and you can replace $('div') by $(this) if you touch the btn because this works about the function above

```
 $('btn').click( function () { 
     $('div').style.display = "none";
 });
```

OR

```
$('btn').click( function () { 
    $('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're adding the menu html dynamically, if so, a simple `.click()` function won't do the trick.

What you'll want to do is something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    $('.element-you-want-to-remove').remove();
});
```

Comment: I think i am using the wrong element (.E_Trigger_WrapperInner), this is removing all the text from the element but not the element it's self, what element should I be removing?

Comment: You haven't given enough information in your question for me to answer that. If I had to guess, It would be the parent of `.E_Trigger_WrapperInner`